# Game capture for Linux

Tags: linux, screen-recording, gaming

I want a software to record some Steam games running on Linux.

Requirements:

- Record full screen
- Set FPS
- Record microphone and game audio out of the box

Comment: I've had a good experience with OBS, which @AidenGrossman recommended. It can record anything, and even works with Wine games. Once set up, it's really simple to use. It also supports compositing, so you can sort of do some very basic video editing (e.g. watermark).

Comment: Doesn't Steam have in-built support for video capture?

Comment: @Mast Source to that information, please. I've heard something about that, but AFAIK it's only for the steam beta users.

Comment: One method is [liteCam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/269290/), a Steam app for capturing Steam apps. There must be more around.

Comment: @Mast LiteCam is able to run on Linux?

Comment: I haven't tested on Games but you can try [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/).

Comment: @Firelord I've tried. But lacks options to record audio from the game and microphone at the same time. It is possible to achieve, but in a too complex way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/).

It has support for most Linux distros and it has a set dos option. It does take a while to set it up though to get good quality recordings.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [recordMyDesktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RecordMyDesktop):

- can record full screen
- free
- set FPS
- can [record microphone and game audio](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/p1_2b.php)